# changing data frame from character to numeric

Tags: r

I have a large data frame with names columns and rows. For some reason the numbers in the data frame are listed as characters when I check with the below sapply function. I have tried to change to numeric as below but it changes the data frame - removes the names from the rows and is no longer a data frame. I cannot list the columns to change by hand as >100 columns and ensembl gene ID names as column names and DE1 etc as row names. Data frame is samples. 
sample of data looks like this:

``````````
     EN00000345    EN00000456    EN00000067
DE1   1.47           7.2          -1.23
DR16  3.4            6.5           0.2
C20   2.7            8.7           7.8 
DR12  4.5            3.2           12.1 
`````````
sapply(samples, mode)

fwrite(samples, "some.name.temp")
  samples<- fread("some.name.temp", colClasses = "numeric")


also tried

samples <- lapply(samples, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
``````````

return data is no longer a data frame and looks like:

```
    EN00000345    EN00000456    EN00000067
1     1.47           7.2          -1.23
2     3.4            6.5          0.2
3     2.7            8.7          7.8
```

Comment: Try `samples[] <- lapply(samples, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

Comment: If you have the `list` output to `samples`, it should be a `list` of vectors, but in the output showed it is not the case.  Can you check the `str` of original dataset

Comment: Structure of original dataset is characters and the code you suggest I have tried and output removes the rownames. thank you though

Comment: It should work if it is a data.frame.  Probably not a data.frame then

Comment: Okay, I will double check. Thank you kindly

Comment: The reason is `mtcars[] <- lapply(mtcars, as.character); head(mtcars, 2)`

Comment: The str on the original data reads; I am not sure why it is not working then? str(samples)  data.frame': 28 obs. of  57955 variables:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this code (df=name of your dataframe) :

```
for(j in 1:ncol(df)){
  df[,j]=as.numeric(df[,j])
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! This works, I have struggled for over two days with this... thank you! Have a good weekend